# Create multiple files based on an output of a custom SSIS component

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a custom SSIS DataFlow component which has three output columns:

```
Id
Name
Content
```

Here is a screenshot of the components output properties:
[image]

The component returns multiple of these result sets. I am able to pipe the result into a **Flat File Destination** which gives me something like this:

```
{E007818F-B9B9-46FF-9231-07367EB96C4F}, nameA.csv, just a text
{9A36EC87-73BC-497D-9592-47FC119CB6E5}, nameB.csv, another text
```

I need to write each of these result sets into a *separate* file which name should be the **name** property and the content should be the **content** property of the result set. So the desired output in this case are two files:

---

**nameA.csv**

```
just a text
```

**nameB.csv**

```
another text
```

---

Unfortunately the result set count is dynamic so I can't just create multiple Flat File Destinations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the data into two separate files, you need to use a "Conditional Split" transformation after the source component. In the editor, create a condition for each result set split, for example

- for split 1:
  Output Name: nameA, Condition: Content == "nameA"
- for split 2:
  Output Name: nameB, Condition: Content == "nameB"

Configure a Flat file destination for each of the files. Then drag the green connectors from the Conditional Split component to the relevant destination component.

--Updated

Making it dynamic is more complex...

You need to start with an **Execute SQL** task that returns all names in the Name field; store the result set in an object variable. Then link this to a **For-each Loop Container** that contains a **Data Flow** task. Configure the For-each loop to use an **ADO Enumerator** and select the object variable created above. Also configure a **Variable Mapping** to store the Name in the current Enumeration (this will be used later for the filename).

In the Data-Flow task, the Source component should be a SELECT statement with WHERE name = 'Name in object variable'. On the destination connection manager properties, configure an Expression for the ConnectionString = variable created in the For-each loop above. This will give each file the name of the current Name in the iteration.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know the names at design time since they are dynamic and can be up to hundreds of result sets returned from the component. Your solution is static - isn't it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update. Unfortunately I doubt this will work because I don't have a SQL Server to execute some SQL but a custom component which returns the output - Or do I miss something? Anyway, upvoted!

Comment: Thanks. You could first load the output into a SQL Server table. You can install a free Express edition if you do not have any in your environment. Just thought I should mention.